# Refresh Token for Quickbooks expiring after 1 day

Tags: php, token, quickbooks

I've built an app that connects to Quickbooks using OAuth 2 with the official Quickbooks PHP SDK.

I get two tokens:

- Access token (Expiring after 60 minutes)
- Refresh token (Expiring after 100 days)

The Refresh token is used to get a new Access token.
However, by requesting a new access token I also receive a new refresh token that I save in the database.

The previous refresh token will be forced to expire. But the new refresh token is invalid already.

I have built a CRON job that request a new refresh token every 15 minutes. I do get a new refresh token but this one is invalid (Error : "invalid_grant"). (See the code below)

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
$dataService->setMinorVersion("9");
        $OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();

        $accessToken = $OAuth2LoginHelper->refreshToken();
        $dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessToken);

        $token->previous_token = $token->last_token;
        $token->last_token = $accessToken->getRefreshToken();

        if($token->last_token != $token->previous_token){
            if($token->save()){
                mail('mymail', 'New token !', "Token updated!!!!");
            }
        }
```